# Bootstrap table and width controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML table with 3 columns styled with bootstrap. All code is in a modal window. I need the first column's width to be equal to 100px, second column 300px and third column 200px. I have diferent inputs in a second column. Now i need to set a different width in the input controls. How can I do this?

I have this:

×
                Actualizar Usuario
            
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                Otros ppp:
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                Listo con clases
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                adsasfadsfads

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bootstrap, why do you need fixed sizes? The whole point of Bootstrap is responsive behaviors. In your case, just apply any width you need to your columns. Otherwise, if you mean proportional widths for each col, use this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col1">col 1</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col2">col 2</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col3">col 3</div>
```

then in CSS

```
.col1{max-width:100px;}
.col2{max-width:200px;}
.col3{max-width:300px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS:
.col-a {
  width:100px
}
.col-b {
  width:300px
}
.col-c {
  width:200px
}
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
           <td class="col-a">a</td>
           <td class="col-b">b</td>
           <td class="col-c">c</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```